# How do I get some objects to be rendered with perspective, some rendered as orthographic in the game engine?

Tags: game-engine, orthographic

I use Blender 2.79 (outdated but my ancient graphics card doesn't support 2.8 so I use it).

I am making a title screen for a game I'm working on. In the screen, there is a 3D background and 2D buttons to play the game.

I want the background to be rendered with perspective but I want the buttons to be rendered in orthographic.

I have tried using the "Add Overlay Scene" actuator but then the buttons are not clickable.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a camera to render orthographic if you render the 3D and 2D objects separately.  Although, for a game, wouldn't you just make the buttons separate anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have asked it, I realized that it wouldn't really make sense. If there are some objects rendered as orthographic, it would create all sorts of overlapping issues